# Same JKS file for keystore and truststore advantages

Tags: java, ssl, keystore, x509

application A calls webservice application B

mutual authentication.

we have a applicationA certificate   . certificate signed by a CA named C. That is the only single certificate content in a jks file

we have used  that same jks file as application A keystore and truststore.  It is working fine.

My understanding here is, when app A calls appB,,  appB sends its certificate which is also signed by CA named C.
This certificate is accepted by appA because in appA trsustore , we have another cert which is signed by same CA named C.

Then, when appA sends cert to appB as part of client authentication, same thing happens

Is this understanding of SSL correct . can you guys please advise. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It's correct understanding but incorrect usage. A keystore is private. It contains your private key. A truststore contains nothing but public certificates. You should not use the same file for both purposes. Your identity and whom you trust are two completely different issues.

Comment: Hi @EJP, thanks for reply, this is point where i am getting unclear.  I read similar private key concern in other threads also .  since jks contains only one certificate.   also per my learning understanding, certificate contain only public key. so, we should not have any security issues here right?  both keystore and trustore jks has only public key as it is certificate only. is it wrong undertstanding

Comment: No. Read what I wrote. A keystore contains your private key. You started by creating a keypair, then you generated a CSR, then you got it signed, then you imported the signed certificate.

Comment: Hi @EJP ,thanks ,ihave onemoredoubt on SSL.in one way ssl,the client is presented with the server certificate andclient verifies CAname on certificate is part of trustore.If thatis true,then verify,whether the server B is really B,this is done with digitialsignature.here is my doubt.Whose private key is used to do the digital signature?is it the CA's private key or the serverB's private key. because if CA's private key is used, it only validates that the CA is really the one who claims it is.Only if the serverB's private key is used ,only then we can say that, the doc came from serverB right?

Comment: The server's private key. The server doesn't *have* the CA's private key. Private keys are, err, private. That's how the system works.That's why the server shouldn't have the client's private key, and the client shouldn't have the server's private key. That's why you shouldn't share keystores.

Comment: Thanks @EJP for clarifying